# How to scroll to the next video on user scroll

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i am building a video sharing app with ionic, a lot of videos on the page and each video is occupying almost all the height of the page, what i want to achieve is that when the user scrolls up, it will automatically place the next video at the bottom at video point of the screen and when the user scrolls down, it will automatically place the previous video at viewpoint of the screen.

Here is my code

the video.page.scss
the video.page.html

```
<div class="DivFyll DivVid" id="deyDiv_{{i}}" *ngFor="let video of videos; let i=index">
    <video class="video" [autoplay]="i==0?true:false" [poster]="service.ApiURL+video.thumbs_path" #player playsinline [id]="i" loop preload="auto">
        <source [src]="service.ApiURL+video.vid_path" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

the video.page.scss

```
ion-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    --background-color: transparent !important;
    .DivFyll {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .DivVid {
        position: relative;
    }
    video {
        background-color: transparent;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: 80%;
        object-fit: fill;
        margin-top: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
    }
}
```

Please does anyone knows how i can implement this with javascript or ionic

Answer (score 0):

This Scroller Component Might Help:

Create Scroll Component Like this:

Create EventListener For Scroll, Then When User Scroll You get the event and with translate 3d or anything you want change the content of scroller component.

with ng-content you can embed any other component inside scroller component.

Html File:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

TS File:

```
export class ScrollerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Output() scrollChange: EventEmitter<ScrollerEventArgs> = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;
  scrollYPos: number = 0;
  scrollXPos: number = 0;
  prevScrollYPos: number = 0;
  prevScrollXPos: number = 0;
  element: HTMLElement;
  scrollLength: number;
  start: number;
  end: number;
  private previousStart: number;
  private previousEnd: number;
  private rowHeightCache: RowHeightCache = new RowHeightCache();
  private scrollListener: any;

  constructor(element: ElementRef, private ngZone: NgZone) {
    this.element = element.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.scrollListener = this.onScrolled.bind(this);
      this.element.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollListener);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.element.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollListener);
  }

  onScrolled(event: MouseEvent) {
    // debugger
    const dom: Element = event.currentTarget as Element;
    this.scrollYPos = dom.scrollTop;
    this.scrollXPos = dom.scrollLeft;

    let direction = null;
    if (this.scrollYPos < this.prevScrollYPos) {
      direction = 'up';
    } else if (this.scrollYPos > this.prevScrollYPos) {
      direction = 'down';
    }

    if (this.prevScrollYPos !== this.scrollYPos || this.prevScrollXPos !== this.scrollXPos) {
      if (direction && this.virtualScroll) {
        this.chunkRows();
        let topPadding = this.rowHeight * this.start;
        if (this.rowHeightProp) {
          topPadding = this.rowHeightCache.getRowOffset(this.start - 1);
        }
        this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
          requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.content.nativeElement.style.transform = `translateY(${topPadding}px)`;
          });
        });
      }

      this.scrollChange.emit({
        direction,
        scrollYPos: this.scrollYPos,
        scrollXPos: this.scrollXPos
      });
      this.prevScrollYPos = this.scrollYPos;
      this.prevScrollXPos = this.scrollXPos;
    } else if (this.scrollXPos === 0 ) {
      this.scrollChange.emit({
        direction,
        scrollYPos: this.scrollYPos,
        scrollXPos: this.scrollXPos
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Update: RowHeightCache Class Added

```
export class RowHeightCache {

  private cache: number[] = [];

  calcScrollLength(totalRecords: number) {
    return this.cache[totalRecords - 1];
  }

  initCache(rows: any[], rowHeightProp: string) {
    const size = rows.length;
    this.cache = new Array(size);
    for (let i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      this.cache[i] = 0;
    }
    rows.forEach((row, i) => {
      for (let index = i; index < size; index++) {
        this.cache[index] += row[rowHeightProp];
      }
    });
  }

  calcRowIndex(offsetY: number): number {
    if (offsetY === 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    let pos = -1;
    const dataLength = this.cache.length;

    for (let i = dataLength; i >= 0; i--) {
      const nextPos = pos + i;
      if (nextPos < dataLength && offsetY >= this.cache[nextPos]) {
        offsetY -= this.cache[nextPos];
        pos = nextPos;
      }
    }
    return pos + 1;
  }

  getRowOffset(rowIndex: number) {
    if (rowIndex < 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return this.cache[rowIndex];
  }

}
```

Comment: how can do that, should I add the `<ng-content></ng-content>` under the for-loop or before the for-loop

Comment: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: RowHeightCache is not defined
ReferenceError: RowHeightCache is not defined`

Comment: some variables and methods are not defined as `rowHeight, virtualScroll, chunkRows(), rowHeightProp`

Comment: You don't need all the variables, pick what you need

Comment: Check RowHeightCache Class Added @EloikeDavid